# Parameter Substitution on Left Side of Variable Assignment - BASH and Arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, variable-assignment, variable-substitution

I am processing some folders that each represent a page of a book. E.g. "Iliad-001" would be Book=Iliad, Page=001.

I want to iterate through all of the folders, create an array for each book and add an entry to that array for each page that is found, so that I can `echo ${Iliad[@]}` at the end of my script and it will give me a nice list of all the pages it found.

The catch I'm having is adding values to an array with a dynamic name. Here's the code that I think is intuitive (but clearly not right):

```
for j in */; do
        vol_name=$(basename "$j" | sed 's/\(.*\)-[0-9]*/\1/')
        page_name=$(basename "$j" | sed 's/.*-\([0-9]*\)/\1/')
        $vol_name+=( "$page_name" )
done
```

This returns:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `"$page_name"'
```

If I change the variable assignment to this `$vol_name+="( "$page_name" )"` I get a little closer:

```
Iliad+=( 001 ): command not found
```

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Comment: Your `$(` inline nested code was terminated with sed's regex and so it's telling you that `-[0-9]*\/1/')\npage_name` is an invalid token.  Your sed command needs more powerful delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work using `eval`.

BTW, you do not need to run `sed`.

```
#! /bin/bash

for j in */; do
        j=$(basename "$j")
        vol_name=${j%-*}
        page_name=${j#*-}
        eval "$vol_name+=('$page_name')"
done    
echo ${Iliad[@]}
```

Comment: Wonderful answer! I guess I don't really understand what eval does. And I didn't even think about being able to remove those extra characters during the substitution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Seth: See `help eval`. It interprets the argument as a shell command. It is a very powerful but also dangerous builtin.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```sh
declare $vol_name+=( "$page_name" )
```